# How fast does Drupal send email?

Tags: 6, emails

My SMTP server has sending limit up to 5 messages per second. On Drupal 6 site I have up to 500 users in organic groups to whom I would like to send newsletter.

What sending limit should I set for successful broadcast? Does Drupal send messages momentarily or during longer period?

**UPDATE**

I use Messages & Notifications modules which allow me to limit

- number of messages
- sending time in seconds
- sending time in % of cron time

The only way to solve my problem I've found up to now is limiting the number of messages to 5 and setting cron to run every 15 minutes. But it is very sad to wait whole day to send about 500 messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start tracing from [`drupal_mail()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7), you will end up in the MailSystem.  The [`DefaultMailSystem::mail()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.mail.inc/function/DefaultMailSystem%3A%3Amail/7) method sends out mail, unless another module has done otherwise.  This hands off the email to the PHP [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, which does something system dependent.

As far as I been able to tell when I have debugged email problems, Drupal doesn't do any throttling.  Typically, PHP doesn't throttle either.  After that, it really varies and totally depends on the php.ini settings and other server setup.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But there is a way to limit sending mail - I use Messages & Notifications (updated question).

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with mails not reaching a custom Google apps email address from the default mail function. Therefor I use [SMTP](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module to handle my emails. It connects to every mail account(supports SMTP), and uses that to send a mail.

It works with Google Apps, and mail is sent instantly.

Comment: I also use SMTP module, otherwise I wouldn't be able to send emails via SMTP. And I also used free Google Apps account, but it allows sending up to 500 messages per day. Recentrly I've subscribed to AWS SES account, but it has limitation of 5 emails/second.